# Display KML file on Google earth with Google Cardboard

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-earth, google-cardboard

I would like to build an app/website which displays a KML File (or at least some simple 3D models) for google cardboard but I haven't found any way to do so. The idea would be to have some kind of "immersive" app to view the 3D models.
It seems that there is no way to display a Google Aarth view in an app or webpage on Android, and that I can't reuse the Google Earth view in the Cardboard app to display a KML file.
Do you have any idea how to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Is Earth view essential for your project? Can you just use Streetview or Satellite map type?

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point what you want to do does not seem feasible but you could always report a feature request in GMaps Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Comment: @KayAnn we couldn't find any alternative since we need the 3 building for this project. We ave up the idea, but let's hope google bring a google earth euivalent running on webGL one day so that we can embed it in a simple web page